# Macromize a tikzfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I have this figure (/ 2 figures)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\xfigscale}{.5}
\newcommand{\yaxscale}{.75}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{\xfigscale\textwidth}
          \centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
          \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[
            scale only axis, 
            height=\yaxscale\textwidth,
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={->},
            x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
            y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            xlabel={X},
            ylabel={Y}]
          \addplot[black,samples=100,domain=0:100] {x};
          \end{axis}
          \end{tikzpicture}
}
          \caption{a}
          \label{fig:a}
     \end{subfigure}

     \begin{subfigure}[b]{\xfigscale\textwidth}
          \centering
          \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
          \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[
            scale only axis, 
            height=\yaxscale\textwidth,
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={->},
            x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
            y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            xlabel={X},
            ylabel={Y}]
          \addplot[black,samples=100,domain=0:100] {sqrt(x)};
          \end{axis}
          \end{tikzpicture}
}
          \caption{b}
          \label{fig:b}
     \end{subfigure}
\caption{cap}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Since there are some of these and only the y label and the function changes, I thought it might be possible to write a command to "add" the rest, i. e. the things which do not change, but I dont know how. This is what I tried:

```
    \newenvironment{splot}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[scale only axis,
    height=\yaxscale\textwidth,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={->},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
    xlabel={X},
    ylabel={#1}]}
    {\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}}

    \newcommand{plotfun}[1]{\addplot[
    black,samples=100,domain=0:100]{#1};}

\begin{document}

    \begin{splot}[$Y label$]
    \plotfun{sqrt(x)}
    \end{splot}

\end{document}
```

but apparently `\addplot[black,samples=100,domain=0:100]{#1};` cannot be put into a command like that.

Also is it possible to have both figures side by side. All the time they are in a column and not in a row, even though I tried to shrink them already...?

Update: So I took David's hint and skipped defining a new `addplot` which is probably more difficult. The following code compiles now, but the figures just dont stay side by side. Why so?

```
\begin{figure}
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{\xfigscale\textwidth}
          \centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
   \begin{splot}{$Y label$}
    \addplot[black,samples=100,domain=0:100]{x};
    \end{splot}
    }
          \caption{a}
          \label{fig:a}
     \end{subfigure}

     \begin{subfigure}[b]{\xfigscale\textwidth}
          \centering
          \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
   \begin{splot}{$Y label$}
    \addplot[black,samples=100,domain=0:100]{sqrt(x)};
    \end{splot}
    }
          \caption{b}
          \label{fig:b}
     \end{subfigure}
\caption{cap}
 \end{figure}
```

Comment: Ypu have defined splot to take one mandatory argument so it needs `{}`  not `[]` around that argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Using Styles (Recommend Approach):

   You should use `tikzset` to define your own styles. Below, I defined `My Axis Style` for your axis style, and `My Plot Style` for your plot:

   [image]

   ### Notes:

   - Removing the blank line between the two sub figures will put the figures next to each other.  This is the similar to the behavior in normal text paragraphs where a blank line indicated the start of a new paragraph.

---

2. Custom Environment:

   To main problem with the custom environment that you were trying to define was the line

   ```
   \newcommand{plotfun}{...}
   ```

   It needed to be

   ```
    \newcommand{\plotfun}{...}
   ```

   The alternative solution below shows you how to have a custom environment and provides an optional parameter to `splot` and `\plotfun` that allows further customization. For illustative purposes, I used the optional parameter to  `splot` to alter the axis style of the first plot, and the optional parameter to `\plotfun` to alter the line style:

   [image]

---

### Code: Using styles:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\xfigscale}{.5}
\newcommand{\yaxscale}{.75}

\tikzset{/pgfplots/My Axis Style/.style={
            scale only axis, 
            height=\yaxscale\textwidth,
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={->},
            x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
            y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            xlabel={X},
            ylabel={Y},
    }
}

\tikzset{My Plot Style/.style={black,samples=100,domain=0:100, ultra thick}}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{\xfigscale\textwidth}
          \centering
          \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% <--- Note
          \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[My Axis Style]
              \addplot[My Plot Style, blue] {x};
          \end{axis}
          \end{tikzpicture}%
           }
          \caption{a}
          \label{fig:a}
     \end{subfigure}%   <--- Note
    %                   <--- Note
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{\xfigscale\textwidth}
          \centering
          \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% <--- Note
          \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[My Axis Style]
              \addplot[My Plot Style, red] {sqrt(x)};
          \end{axis}
          \end{tikzpicture}%  <--- Note
          }
          \caption{b}
          \label{fig:b}
     \end{subfigure}
    \caption{cap}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Code: Custom Environment

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\xfigscale}{.5}
\newcommand{\yaxscale}{.75}

\tikzset{/pgfplots/My Axis Style/.style={
            scale only axis, 
            height=\yaxscale\textwidth,
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={->},
            x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
            y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            xlabel={X},
            ylabel={Y},
    }
}

\tikzset{My Plot Style/.style={black,samples=100,domain=0:100, ultra thick}}


\newenvironment{splot}[2][]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[scale only axis,
    height=\yaxscale\textwidth,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={->},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
    xlabel={X},
    ylabel={#2},
    #1
    ]
}{%
    \end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}%
}

%% Note The command name is "\plotfun" not "plotfun"
\newcommand{\plotfun}[2][]{\addplot[My Plot Style,#1]{#2};}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{\xfigscale\textwidth}
          \centering
          \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
            \begin{splot}[axis line style={<->, magenta},]{$Y_1$}
                \plotfun[blue]{x}
            \end{splot}%
           }
          \caption{$y=x$}
          \label{fig:a}
     \end{subfigure}%   <--- Note
    %                   <--- Note
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{\xfigscale\textwidth}
          \centering
          \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
            \begin{splot}{$Y_2$}
                \plotfun[red]{sqrt(x)}
            \end{splot}%
          }
          \caption{$y=\sqrt{x}$}
          \label{fig:b}
     \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Twp plots via custom environment.}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: so this is how it works. But the `addplot` command cannot be put in another one, can it? Has it to do with optional arguments?

Comment: Why is the `    %` neccessary? Is it what keeps the figures side by side?

Comment: @embert: Defined a new style for your plot as well, and added not regarding the `%`.  Using styles is preferable to defining your environment as I believe that that will have issues if you try to use the `external`ization library.

Comment: @embert: Provided a custom environment solution as well.  Also, found another missing % that should have been there in the first solution as well.